# Why are my badblocks results inconsistant with SMART results for an SSD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd

I have an SSD that has been running for years. It was part of a RAID0 that failed. The other SSD in the array was definitely bad - it doesn't show up at all when I plug it into a computer anymore. I'm trying to figure out if this SSD that I'm dealing with is also bad.

An extended SMART test with the disks utility in Linux tells me that "Disk is OK". When I run badblocks on it with `sudo badblocks -w -s -v /dev/sdc`, and leave it running overnight, I had a huge list of errors. It didn't complete by morning, and I had to interrupt it, but it was somewhere around this stage: `one, 20:19:28 elapsed. (0/13/5396172 errors)`.

I guess what I'm wondering is: if there are this many errors that badblocks is running into, how is SMART not seeing them? Is my SSD bad or not?

The results of my SMART test are below:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
[sudo] password for tal: 
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.6.13-200.fc31.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB
Serial Number:    S1DBNSAD968844W
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 8a0021de5
Firmware Version: EXT0DB6Q
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jul  3 08:15:18 2020 MDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 4800) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  80) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       53840
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       976
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   094   094   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       65
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   062   047   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       3718773
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       183
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       22842562290

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       212         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: SMART is not always smart.......

Comment: 53840 power-on hours? Wow. Perform an extended offline SMART test to get up-to-date information. You also might want to TRIM the entire device before performing further testing.

Answer (score 0):

The following SMART parameter might be a cause for problems.

> 199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       3718773

Unfortunately I am lacking the experience with SSDs to say if this is a typical value or not.

The reason for the different behaviour might be the fact that SMART is operating on disk level (only).
When running the badblock command the physical transport way is involved as well.